# Clustering Algorithm for for Different types of dimension

Tags: clustering, model-based-clustering

I want to cluster radar data but using its position (x,y) and its radial velocity. As position parameters have same units (meter) but radial velocity is in m/s. Which algorithm can be used for such application ?

Comment: what's wrong with "normal" clustering algorithms? You could scale / normalize the data to make the units irrelevant

Comment: It depends on the purpose of clustering.  How do you intend to interpret any clusters you find?  @nope Scaling or normalizing alone will not necessarily solve this problem in a meaningful or useful way.  To see why not, just contemplate alternative ways of representing the data, such as with points in phase space (a four-dimensional space): the scaled or normalized data will have a different geometry and therefore can yield different clustering solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Im my opinion, when you use "classical" clustering algorithms, you only compare values of a variable with other value of this variable.

To be more precise, you're going to compare X_axis with other X_axis values, Y_axis values with other Y_axis values, and therefore radial velocity measures with other radial velocity measures. Depending on the clustering algorithm you'll used, you will have (or not) to scale your data (this topic is already cover for many algorithm).

Hoping this help,

Rémi